# How to add Localization Item for iOS app in Flutter?

Tags: ios, localization, flutter

In Flutter Internationalization document there is a small info for updating the iOS app bundle for localization (h***s://flutter.io/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#appendix-updating-the-ios-app-bundle).

I try to follow the section and open the files with Xcode but cannot add Turkish, Russian, German from the editor.

I open the iOS/Runner.xcworkspace and open the Info.plist and then find the Information Property List item and I can select add Item and add Localization but when I expand and add new Language there is no Language for Turkish, Russian or German...

Any help?

Comment: Result in here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24879

Comment: did you end up finding a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter right now doesn't require you to modify anything in the iOS build to configure the localization. Following this [guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization), the `localization` plugin should generate .arb files which should contain the localization texts for the app. The .arb files should be located in `${FLUTTER_PROJECT}/lib/l10n/`